# Need to construct an API list arry

Tags: arrays, json

I need to create: A set of at least 4 clickable elements,

Generate the clickable elements using a predefined JSON array containing JSON
Objects. Each JSON object contains:
▪ the name that is displayed in the clickable element.
▪ a string used as the value of an attribute of the clickable element.

But I am new to jquery and JSON. I need to construct the data from an API but for now, I have this. This works and gives me the images of the API. But I really don't know how to fetch the other data and show this on my website. If anyone can help me out, let me know!

$(document).ready(function (e) {

```
$("#TheSubmitButton").on("click", function(event){
    $("#card-container").empty();

    
    event.preventDefault();

    var pokemon = $("#searchInput")
        .val()
        .trim();
    console.log(pokemon);
    


$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=name:" + pokemon
    
}).then(function(response){
    for (var i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++) {
        var pokemonCard = $("<img class='pkmn-card'>");
        pokemonCard.attr("src", response.data[i].images.small);
        $("#card-container").append(pokemonCard);
    }
    console.log(response.data[19].rarity);
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, do the exact same thing you're already doing with the picture.  The commands are slightly different (I used .text() instead of .attr() to set the text of the element containing the name) but the idea is the same.

You will likely have to figure out how to set up the elements you are adding both structurally and semantically so that you can set an overall styling for the document, but this will get the data in.

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {

  $("#TheSubmitButton").on("click", function(event){
    
    $("#card-container").empty();
    event.preventDefault();
    var pokemon = $("#searchInput").val().trim();
    console.log(pokemon);
    
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=name:" + pokemon
    
    }).then(function(response){
      for (var i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++) {
        var pokemonCard = $("<img class='pkmn-card'>");
        pokemonCard.attr("src", response.data[i].images.small);
        $("#card-container").append(pokemonCard);
        var pokemonName = $("<div></div>");
        pokemonName.text(response.data[i].name);
        $("#card-container").append(pokemonName);
      }
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='searchInput' type='text' />
<button id='TheSubmitButton'>CLICK</button>
<div id='card-container'></div>
```

For instance, here is a slightly more involved implementation that includes some other data points and floats the containers left so that they are displayed horizontally instead of vertically:

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {

  $("#TheSubmitButton").on("click", function(event){

    $("#card-container").empty();
    event.preventDefault();
    var pokemon = $("#searchInput").val().trim();
    console.log(pokemon);

    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=name:" + pokemon

    }).then(function(response){
      for (var i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++) {

        var pokeTainer = $("<div class='poketainer'></div>");

        var pokemonCard = $("<img class='pkmn-card'>");
        pokemonCard.attr("src", response.data[i].images.small);
        pokeTainer.append(pokemonCard);

        var pokemonName = $("<div></div>");
        pokemonName.text(response.data[i].name);
        pokeTainer.append(pokemonName);
        
        try {            
          var pokemonEvolve = $("<div></div>");
          pokemonEvolve.text('Evolves to: ' + response.data[i].evolvesTo[0]);
          pokeTainer.append(pokemonEvolve);
        } catch {}
   
        var pokemonFlavor = $("<div></div>");
        pokemonFlavor.text(response.data[i].flavorText);
        pokeTainer.append(pokemonFlavor);
                    
        $("#card-container").append(pokeTainer);

      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.poketainer {float:left; max-width:250px; min-height: 550px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='searchInput' type='text' />
<button id='TheSubmitButton'>CLICK</button>
<div id='card-container'></div>
```

Comment: note, I only tested this on eevee and pikachu.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It didn't work on other pokemon at first because some of them can not evolve. I changed the array [0] to nothing and now it works! Great help thanks a lot!

Comment: I was also wondering if there is a way to make it so when U click on a pokemon card it shows that specific card with its stats and stuff. I want it so when you click on a card it moves to the stats box.

Comment: And is there a way for me to give each variable a button? So it would be like: "click on the  name button" and when you click it it appends the name to the image.

Comment: I see.  I added a try/catch block around the evolvesTo section and tried a couple of different ones.  You can also check for the existence of the property before you try to do anything with it BUT what you really would do is take the element creation steps out of the main loop and put them into a function, and put all the error trapping, etc, in the function.

Comment: I'm glad to see this helped you.  If it solved your problem, please accept it as the answer (and maybe even upvote :) ).  For the other questions, yes, there is probably a way to do what you're asking, but a) I am not positive I understand what you are asking and b) they should be separate questions.  So why don't you get some clarity on what you want and how to ask it, and then put some new questions up.